# 2nd-order Butterworth for an 8 Ω tweeter

Tags: audio, filter

I want to cross it at 4600 Hz and want it to drop off faster than a first-order filter.

I used two different crossover calculators. Why is there a 0.39 mH inductor across the tweeter's positive and negative terminals? How would that 3.06 μF capacitor interact with that inductor? Does it just increase the slope of the crossover point instead of just using a capacitor, if so, how does it do this? I found a good 40 mH inductor and a 3 μF poly cap to use.

Comment: The cutoff is determined by f=1/(2pi*sqrt(LC)  bu the slope cannot be changed with only 2 elements, you need more

Comment: 0.4uH range is correct. 40 mH is no good.  Why do you want a faster cutoff?

Answer (score 1):

Your Butterworth calculator is correct for a single pair LC crossover which gives a 2nd order slope and cutoff of 4.6 kHz at half power or -3dB.

Normally when you want a steeper cutoff, it is defined by some secondary frequency and attenuation. However it is well known that each L or C component with resistance defines a frequency attenuation of -20dB/ decade per order of slope and number of LC unique elements.

If I assume you wanted the same cutoff in a 4th order filter, and you have access to 390 uH (which must be) **air coils** and 3 uF metal film capacitors, with a slight tweaking of values [I can suggest this.](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%204%20109071352.13006356%0Aw%20880%20352%20944%20352%200%0Ar%20944%20352%20944%20464%200%208%0Ag%20816%20464%20816%20480%200%0Ag%20944%20464%20944%20480%200%0AO%20944%20352%20992%20352%200%0A170%20752%20352%20720%20352%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AB%20752%20304%20816%20528%203%20Box%0Ac%20752%20352%20816%20352%200%200.00000306%200%0Al%20816%20352%20816%20464%200%200.00015000000000000001%200%0AB%20816%20304%20880%20528%203%20Box%0Ag%20880%20464%20880%20480%200%0Ac%20816%20352%20880%20352%200%200.00000306%200%0Al%20880%20352%20880%20464%200%200.00039%200%0As%20752%20304%20816%20304%200%201%20true%0Aw%20752%20352%20752%20304%200%0Aw%20816%20352%20816%20304%200%0A) Tolerance values will vary your results.

Pressing the momentary switch converts it from 4th order to a 2nd order HPF filter.  The speaker impedance also matters as it affects the damping or hump ar the corner frequency. Feel free to alter the LC values with your mouse thumbwheel over the component.

C1=C2= 3.06 uF
L1 = 150 uH
L2 = 390 uH
f-3dB = 4.5 kHz

However, you should be aware that higher-order filters also have a steeper phase shift. Phase shift mismatch in crossovers adds to phase distortion in this region, which reduces the perception of instrument position in high-quality music as if you were visualizing on-stage.  This is optimized with linear-phase electrostatic speakers but also makes the sound waves very directional for the sweet spot, so cone or box speakers are more popular.  So there are tradeoffs for precision speaker monitors. Just an FYI

[image]

Speaker impedance tends to be more complex than just 8 Ohms.
Even Z= 2pi*L//Racoustic+ Rresistive being roughly 8 Ohms is just an approximation.

pour s'amuser

[image]